# System calls - functions used by kernel

Tags: c, kernel

I was asked about system calls , what they are, which mode are they used in and if read(), getchar() and sqrt() uses or not system calls.

For the first part I answered that system calls provide a interface between a process and the OS and these are used in kernel mode.

The thing that is bothering me is the fact that for me the only function that uses system calls of those 3 is read().

Am I right? or getchar() and sqrt() also use system calls?

(NOTE: read() from unistd.h getchar() from stdio.h and sqrt() from math.h)

Comment: how do you think `getchar()` get the character ?

Comment: There are/were systems which provide(d) a math library, too.

Comment: yes, i thought about that but isnt it a intermediary function that contains system calls within?

EDIT: Because getchar() and sqrt() use system calls within them.  I can say that both of them are system calls?

Comment: The question said "uses" system calls not "is" a system call...

Comment: True, just to make sure that im thinking right. read() and getchar() are both system calls but sqrt isnt, because as Jose said below : it just makes some calculations?

Comment: One information I want to add here, read() is system call. fread() is  belong to C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between a system and a regular call is that a system call has to issue a trap to the operating system whereas a regular call just calls another user level subroutine. You're right in saying that the difference is in what mode the calls are executed in.

Sqrt is not a system call. All it does is perform a simple calculation. If I remember correctly, both read() and getchar() are system calls because the operating system is the one who handles input/output operations.

Comment: Oh, so read() is a direct system call, getchar() uses system calls within the function so we can see getchar() is a system call too. The only one who isnt a system call is sqrt() because it performes calculations?

Comment: It's not necessarily that getchar() is using system calls, per se, because it's one function. What it does is it gets the next character in the standard input stream. This access to the input/output streams is what regular processes can't do without the operating system, that's why getchar is a system call.